# How can I prevent 'Unrecognized Windows Sockets error', on Apache tomcat 6?

Tags: tomcat6

This is my log and I have tried everything, from changing my port number, to copy `msvcr71.dll` to `system32` and tomcat/bin directory.
The first severe-error message to arise is 'Unrecognized Windows Sockets error'.
Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

> ```
> Apr 20, 2011 10:51:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
> INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the
> ```
>
> java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat
>   6.0\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:40 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
>       INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-1234
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
>       INFO: Initialization processed in 1521 ms
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
>       INFO: Starting service Catalina
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
>       INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.16
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
>       INFO: The listener "listeners.ContextListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been
>   ignored.
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
>       INFO: The listener "listeners.SessionListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been
>   ignored.
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:41 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
>       INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-1234
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:41 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
>       INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:41 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
>       INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/46  config=null
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>       INFO: Server startup in 1631 ms
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
>       INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the
>   java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Tomcat
>   6.0\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:53 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
>       SEVERE: Error initializing endpoint
>       java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:50)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:496)
>         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.init(Http11Protocol.java:176)
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1058)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:677)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:795)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:530)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:550)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:260)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:412)
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
>       SEVERE: Catalina.start
>       LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0:
>   JVM_Bind
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initialize(Connector.java:1060)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initialize(StandardService.java:677)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initialize(StandardServer.java:795)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:530)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:550)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:260)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:412)
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
>       INFO: Initialization processed in 299 ms
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
>       INFO: Starting service Catalina
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
>       INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.16
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
>       INFO: The listener "listeners.ContextListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been
>   ignored.
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
>       INFO: The listener "listeners.SessionListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been
>   ignored.
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:53 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
>       SEVERE: Error starting endpoint
>       java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:50)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.init(JIoEndpoint.java:496)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint.start(JIoEndpoint.java:515)
>         at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.start(Http11Protocol.java:203)
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1131)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:531)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>       SEVERE: Catalina.start: 
>       LifecycleException:  service.getName(): "Catalina";  Protocol handler start failed: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows
>   Sockets error: 0: JVM_Bind
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.start(Connector.java:1138)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:531)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
>       INFO: Server startup in 416 ms
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
>       SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[8005]: 
>       java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
>         at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
>         at java.net.ServerSocket.(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:373)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:642)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:602)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:53 PM org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector pause
>       SEVERE: Protocol handler pause failed
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at org.apache.jk.server.JkMain.pause(JkMain.java:679)
>         at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.pause(JkCoyoteHandler.java:153)
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.pause(Connector.java:1073)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:563)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:744)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:628)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina$CatalinaShutdownHook.run(Catalina.java:671)
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stop
>       INFO: Stopping service Catalina
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:54 PM org.apache.catalina.connector.MapperListener destroy
>       WARNING: Error unregistering MBeanServerDelegate
>       java.lang.NullPointerException
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.MapperListener.destroy(MapperListener.java:162)
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.stop(Connector.java:1179)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stop(StandardService.java:593)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.stop(StandardServer.java:744)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.stop(Catalina.java:628)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina$CatalinaShutdownHook.run(Catalina.java:671)
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:54 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol destroy
>       INFO: Stopping Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-1234
>       Apr 20, 2011 10:51:54 PM org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector stop
>       SEVERE: Coyote connector has not been started

Answer (score 5):

> SEVERE: StandardServer.await:
>   create[8005]: java.net.BindException:
>   Address already in use

You have another instance of Tomcat **already running on the same server and same port**. Shut it down first, and then try to start a new one.